# The optional arguments with argparse[python] description format is not like the defalut one, the option name is appearing twice

Tags: python, command-line-interface, argparse

I have written simple python script to get arguments for city temparature but the help message is not like the default one, it's showing twice. How can I fix this?

```
def get_by_city_args(subparsers):
    city_parser = subparsers.add_parser('city')
    city_parser.add_argument(
        "city",
        help="enter city name to get current temparature"
    )
    city_parser.add_argument(
        "-c", "--country",
        help="country of the city",
        default=""
    )
    city_parser.add_argument(
        "-u", "--units",
        help="M - [DEFAULT] Metric (Celcius, m/s, mm), S - Scientific (Kelvin, m/s, mm),I - Fahrenheit (F, mph, in)",
        default="M"
    )
```

This produces output like this:

```
vatsa@vatsa-VirtualBox:~/cli-weather/cli_weather$ python3 main.py city -h
usage: cli-weather city [-h] [-c COUNTRY] [-u UNITS] city

positional arguments:
  city                  enter city name to get current temparature

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -c COUNTRY, --country COUNTRY
                        country of the city
  -u UNITS, --units UNITS
                        M - [DEFAULT] Metric (Celcius, m/s, mm), S -
                        Scientific (Kelvin, m/s, mm),I - Fahrenheit (F, mph,
                        in)
```

Comment: Notice the difference between the description of -h and -c/-u. I wanted it to look like -h.

Comment: '-h' is a True/False argument.  The others take values along with the flag.  That's normal `argparse` help display.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks.! But It makes the description really weird.

Comment: It's telling your user that they can "-c USA" or "--country USA".  You can change it a bit with a `metavar` parameter.  But forcing it to do something like "-c, --country COUNTRY" or "-c, --country" requires changes to the formatter code.  That's possible, and has been discussed in previous SO, but you need to do some coding.